# URL Rewriting Middleware In ASP.NET Core - printed from the database

Tags: c#, .net-core

That's the way I have to make 301 Moved permanently to a new page from the old side.

I have basically done so that if people get into the old url they will be thrown over to the new url.

How can I do it by taking content from the database.

I work with .net core 2.0

*How do I call the database into Startup.cs?*

Right now I have this piece of code on startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var optionsValue = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRedirect("", "")
            .AddRewrite(@"", "", skipRemainingRules: true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating your own `IRule` and redirecting in the `ApplyRule`.

Comment: Okay, Do you have an article or video where I can see more about it? So I have something to base?

Comment: i have see this here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1204099/ASP-NET-Core-URL-Rewriting